# UIWebView giving only a white screen - Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Since the recent update to Xcode 7, I have found that my webView will no longer load, it will only show a white screen.

I have searched for a solution, to no avail.

I have coded the webView connection as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webviewInstance: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Connect UIWebView to the ordering page

    let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.google.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webviewInstance.loadRequest(requestObj);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the app plist file and add the AppTransportSecurity.
Open your plist file and add this. Search for AppTransportSecurity

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

If you don't add the ATS in your PLIST your link are ignored/blocked. I hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

A while back I remember reading a question here on SO saying that not implementing

```
- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

from [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/) was causing problems.

If that don't solve the issue, you can use the delegate methods to debug your problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely used to delegates, how would this be implemented?

Comment: [This](http://hayageek.com/uiwebview-uiwebviewdelegate-tutorial/) is a Objective C tutorial, but it can give you an idea of how to do it

Comment: You don't have to implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` if you don't want to intercept certain requests. It is an optional method. If it is not implemented all requests will be loaded.